# Apache Cordova: CSS3 transforms

Tags: css, cordova, css-transforms, apache-cordova

I am making a little Application with Apache-Cordova for my mobile phone.
Therefore I want a div and its content to be upside down. I've tried

```
transform: rotation(180deg);
```

and

```
transform: scale(1, -1);
```

so far. In my Firefox they work as desired, but on my mobile phone nothing is changed. So I don't know why or any other possibility to do that.

Does anybody know why this is the case or has some other ideas?

Does Apache Cordova not support CSS3?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The syntax is `rotate(180deg)`, not `rotation(180deg)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the full set of vendor prefixes?

```
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Vendor prefixes are needed on older versions of Android.

Comment: Oh, that worked fine! Didn't thought I would need these, but next time i will try first, then ask such a dumb question :D. It's a Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: Only use -webkit-transform and transform tags. The other one doesn't need it in Cordova apps.